# Множества целых чисел(инициализация с помощью массива)

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, динамические-массивы, множества

Нужно реализовать функции разности множеств и пересечения, не знаю как сделать без set.difference и set.intersection(именно с помощью массивов нужно).

```
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


class Set
{
int n;
int *a;
public:
    Set(int s);
    Add(const Set &obj);
    Set();
    void In();
    void Out();
    bool operator==(Set m)
    {
        if(n!=m.n)
            return false;
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
            if(a[i] != m.a[i])
              return false;
        return true;
    }
    /*
    void f()
{
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(a[i]==e)
        cout<<"Элемент принадлежит множеству: "<<a[i]<<" ";
        else {cout<<"Элемент не принадлежит множествам"<<endl;}
}
*/
};


void Set::In()
{
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];

    }
}

void Set::Out()
{
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cout<<a[i]<<" ";
}

Set::Set(int s)
    {
        n=s;
        a=new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        a[i] = 0;
    }

Set::Set()
    {
       n = 1;
    a = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        a[i] = 0;
}



Set::Add(const Set &obj)
{
   int *tmp=new int[n+obj.n];
   int i;
   for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    tmp[i]=a[i];
   for(i=0;i<obj.n;i++)
    tmp[n+i]=obj.a[i];
   a=tmp;
   n+=obj.n;
}


int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    int n,i,e;
    Set set3;
    cout<<"Введите количество элементов в первом множестве: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    Set set1(n);
    cout<<"Введите количество элементов во втором множестве: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    Set set2(n);
    cout<<"Введите первое множество: "<<endl;
    set1.In();
    cout<<"Введите второе множество: "<<endl;
    set2.In();
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<endl;
    //cout<<"Введите элемент для поиска в одном из множеств: ";
    //cin>>e;
    cout<<"Ваше первое множество"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    set1.Out();
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Ваше второе множество"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    set2.Out();
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"1 - Проверка равенства множеств"<<endl;
    if (set1 == set2)
        cout<<"Множества равны "<<endl;
    else cout<<"Множества не равны "<<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"2 - Объединение множеств"<<endl;
    set1.Add(set2);
    set1.Out();
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"3 - Вычитание множеств"<<endl;

    cout<<"4 - Пересечение множеств"<<endl;


    cout<<"5 - Проверка отношения включения"<<endl;
    cout<<"6 - Проверка принадлежности заданного символа к множеству"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Ну отсортируйте массивы, к отсортированным тоже можно применять функции `set_`...

Comment: Даже если я их отсортирую, я не очень понимаю как будет выглядеть запись, например вот я создал 2 множества с помощью класса Set set1 и Set set2, а дальше я же не могу написать set_intersection(set1.begin и т.д) или я чего-то не понимаю.

Answer (score 3):

> я же не могу написать set_intersection(set1.begin и т.д)

Как раз можете :)

```
int a[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
int b[] = { 5,6,7,8,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23};

int c[100]; // Ну, с достаточным количеством элементов

int n = set_intersection(begin(a),end(a),begin(b),end(b),begin(c))-c;
// Или даже просто так:
// int n = set_intersection(a,a+9,b,b+12,c)-c;
```

Все, в `c` результат пересечения множеств из массивов, а `n` - количество элементов в этом пересечении.

Если это надо тоже писать вручную - ну, напишите:

```
int* set_intersection(int*first1, int*last1,
                      int*first2, int*last2,
                      int*d_first)
{
    while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
        if (*first1 < *first2) {
            ++first1;
        } else  {
            if (!(*first2 < *first1)) {
                *d_first++ = *first1++;
            }
            ++first2;
        }
    }
    return d_first;
}
```